# Working with status codes for JSON APIs

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

When your server understands the request and wants to send back the data client requested, you send a 200. When your server understands the request but you will not send back the data the client requested, you send a 422. And that's exactly how my JSON API works. When a model is saved, I send 200. When model contains validation errors, I send 422:

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @user.persisted?
        format.json do
          render json: { id: @user.id }, status: 200
        end
      else
        format.json do
           render json: { error: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
        end
      end
    end
```

Unfortunately, when I send a 422 to Android, HttpURLConnection throws an exception when trying to access the input stream:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:3001/users/auth/facebook/callback.json
```

Now, if I change 422 to 200 in my JSON API, then no exception is raised and I am able to parse the data.

```
 url = new URL(OMNI_AUTH_CALLBACK);
 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
 urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
 urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
 urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

 OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
 writer.write(getQuery(params[0]));


 writer.flush();
 writer.close();
 os.close();

 int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
 InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
 int data = reader.read();
 while(data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
 }
```

But the response should NOT be a 200, because there was an issue saving the data. What is an Android developer to do?

Comment: ??? So 422 you get an error and 200 you don't get an error and you are saying the response SHOULD not be 200, right? So what is it you need, 422 or 200 and error or no error?

Comment: @user7568042 I already explained it in my question: when the model is not saved, I want to send back a 422. However, when I send 422 to Android, it raises an exception and does not allow me to process the error message JSON response with the 422 status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a non-success response code, read the error stream.

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)_urlConnection;
InputStream _is;
if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
    _is = httpConn.getInputStream();
} else {
     /* error from server */
    _is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
}
```

Here's the bug, closed as WNF:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4513568

The fact that it's throwing FNFE for a 422 response is seriously messed up. If you look at the source for `HttpURLConnection`, it doesn't even define 422.

Comment: Yeah that file not found error threw me off big time. I had no clue what it was talking about.